# Start an iteration from the beginning once condition is satisfied python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
letters = 'abcdefg'    
for i in letters:
        if ...
        #condition that tests something I need
        #once condition is satisfied, something is done, the condition is modified
        # and letters becomes:
                letters = letters.replace(i,'')
                ### Now I want to start this for loop again because my condition
                ### may now be met with the initial letters
```

How do I get my loop to start from the beginning again?

Comment: do you mean restart the "loop" rather than function?

Comment: Sorry, yea I meant restart loop i'll edit title

Comment: what do you mean by `the condition is modified`

Comment: Don't attempt to modify the iterable during the loop. It shouldn't do bad things here, since you're not iterating over a mutable sequence... but it probably won't do what you want. It certainly won't change the sequence you're iterating over.

Comment: a is a variable in my function. i'm testing variables abcdefg on another variable let's call this 'Y'. Once abcde or f is true, that variable is added to the variable Y, thus meaning I would need to retest the initial variables to see if they now satisfy the condition with the new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an approach along these lines (tweak as needed to fit your code):

```
i = 0
while i < len(letters):
    if ....

       letters = letters.replace(letters[i], '')  # probably what you want
       i = 0
    else:
       i += 1
```

The iteration in your loop is controlled by the value of `i`. As long as `i` is less than the length of your string (7) it will keep looping, each time incrementing the value of `i` (which serves as a counter) in the loop. When you set `i = 0` you are (re)starting the counter again.

*Note* that unlike with the for-loop where you had `for i in letters` (and `i` successively  got the value of a letter), `i` is a simple counter, so to access a given letter you have to index into it. I.e., `letters[i]`

Comment: perfect. can't believe it was this easy

Comment: Waiting for the 8 minutes to allow me to accept...One question I have about your code, by putting in i = 0, will that make the iteration start from the beginning again?

Comment: Ok, the thing about your code is that it doesn't start from the beginning anymore which was what I was looking for

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it does start from the beginning. Can you explain why you don't think it does this?

Comment: From what I see of your code, it basically allows the iteration to continue. So for example, if 'c' satisfied the condition, letters will now be 'abdefg' and your code then runs on 'defgab'...that's okay though, it still does what I need the code to do, just thinking that if I needed it to start from the beginning it wouldn't

Comment: @Chowza There's not enough code in your original post to know exactly what you are doing, so perhaps that limits my understanding of your goal, but when you set `i=0` it *does* start the loop over. The iteration only continues when your `if` condition isn't satisfied. But you should pick an answer that you fully understand and believe does what you want it to do.

Comment: Ohhh I see.I didn't realize my code was continuing because the if statement wasn't satisfied. Look good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do what you need:

```
while letters and not breakCondition:
  for i in letters:
    if someLogic():
      letters = letters.replace(i, '')
      break
```